My php form on my website is ending blank submissions to my email
Below is the php code i have on my website. We have been getting some email form submissions that are working but we have also been getting a large amount of empty submissions. When i try to submit a form without filling it out the site wont allow it. BUT lately a. lot have been coming in looking like this.
"Information Submitted:
Name:
Email:
Phone:
Message:
"
Is this someone trying to hack my site?
I am very new to coding/backend web development and have basically taught myself everything through youtube so i definitely need some help.
$userName       = $_POST['name-3'];
$userPhone      = $_POST['name-2'];
$userEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email-2']);
$userMessage    = $_POST['email-3'];

$to             = "ilana@MYSITE.com";
$subject        = "Email from my website";
$body           = "Information Submitted:";

$body .= "\r\n Name: " . $userName;
$body .= "\r\n Email: " . $userEmail;
$body .= "\r\n Phone: " . $userPhone;
$body .= "\r\n Message: " . $userMessage;

mail($to, $subject, $body);///

if (filter_var($userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    
 //email is valid
} else {
    //email is invalid
}

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       $success = "Message successfully sent";
    } else {
        $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
    }
}

My site is hosted on Cpannel through Godaddy. In my web files, there is an error log that tells me "Undefined array key "submit" in /send.php" for each line of the fields below. I feel like this is going to be a super simple fix and I would appreciate the help!
I have tried adding different validations and such but in general I am just confused.

"When i try to submit a form without filling it out the site wont allow it." - just because your form doesn't let the user submit if not all fields have been filled out, doesn't mean I can't send a request to your script from anywhere else. You need to properly check, if you have all the data you need, before you send the mail.

They are probably just bypassing your form and sending requests directly to the php script over http. It's easy to do. Chances are this might be done by bots, or perhaps just an innocent web crawler (e.g. search engine spider). If you want to stop this kind of thing then a) at least have your script check it's really a POST request before proceeding, b) add some validation on the individual POST fields in the php script, so if your client side validation is bypassed it still won't accept empty fields, and c) consider adding a captcha to the form (and verifying it in the php code)
